# i'm new to webpack 3 i want to share my var to other js file how to?

Tags: javascript, webpack

this is my Webpack 3 config:

```
    const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins

const glob = require('glob');

const path = require('path');

/*
 * Frontend Config
 */

const _myPathFront = './assets/my_lib/js/frontend/';
const _myFrontEnd = {
  entry: glob.sync(_myPathFront + '*.js'),
  output: {
    filename: '_my_main_style.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/my_lib/js')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
};


module.exports = [

  Object.assign({} , _myFrontEnd)

];
```

i had one variable to share to my other js file that in Frontend folder:

```
var windowHieght = 0 < window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : screen.Height;
```

how to set this variable in config for share to other js file ?

Comment: Please provide more details. Webpack config is only used server-side when the project is built, so `window` is not even defined there.

Comment: @zerkms I'm pretty sure the OP is just confused about how to export a variable from one file (which is code that will run on the client) and import it in another file.

Comment: @Andy yep, I just wanted to see them explaining it and then realising why their current attempt is unsuccessful :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make any changes to your config, and you don't want to set this variable in your config because the size of the user's browser window or screen is not known at build time.  To share variables between files you simply use `import` and `export` statements.  You can export this variable from a module that will run in the browser:

#### src/windowHeight.js

```
export default 0 < window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : screen.Height;
```

Then import it in another module:

#### src/someOtherModule.js

```
import windowHeight from './windowHeight.js';
```

Then import it from yet another module:

#### src/subfolder/anotherModule.js

```
import windowHeight from '../windowHeight.js';
```

And Webpack will automatically make it work.  `windowHeight.js` does not even need to be in the `entry` section of your webpack config; webpack will automatically include it if a module in the `entry` imports it, or imports another module that imports it, etc.

Also I don't know why you're using `glob.sync` to build a list of files to put in the `entry`, but that's atypical and probably unnecessary.  You probably just need to put a single file in your `entry` and have that file `import` from other files.

#### Warning

`window.innerHeight` can change if the user resizes their browser.   If their window starts very small, it will probably screw up whatever you're trying to do with the window height.  You should listen for window resize events and do something in response to them:

```
function handleResize() {
  // do something with window.innerHeight
}
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

Comment: aw Thank you so much u save my day. i use Glob instead becoz my Folder Frontend had many Js file: around 5-10 so i don't want to write entry with 5-10 line for it.

Comment: I figured, but yeah you don't have to include each file in the `entry`, just the ones that are "entry points" for your code.